# How do I hover and use a stretched-link on an image in the Bootstrap 5 Card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap card with a streched-link to navigate to the content page on clicking on the card.

if I use the stretched-link the hoverImage is not changed.

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="my-image">
                        <img th:src="@{/images/a.png}" class="mainImage card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <img th:src="@{/images/a_hov.png}" class="hoverImage card-img-top" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Content</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">View and update the content</p>
                        <a href="https://www.example.com/content" class="card-link stretched-link"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using for hover.

```
.my-image .mainImage {
  display: block;
}

.my-image .hoverImage {
    display: none;
}

.my-image:hover .mainImage {
  display: none;
}

.my-image:hover .hoverImage {
  display: block;
}
```

Can we use javascript to make hover and stretched-link work?

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript question, and "java css" isn't a thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the entire `.card` gets covered by `.stretched-link::after`. The only elements receiving the hover event are `.card` and `.stretched-link`.
You could just change `.my-image:hover` to `.card:hover`. Yes, that will change the image when you hover over any part of the card but that makes sense semantically as any part of the card is the link.

```css
.my-image .mainImage {
  display: block;
}

.my-image .hoverImage {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .mainImage {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .hoverImage {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="my-image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png?text=Default" class="mainImage card-img-top" alt="...">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png?text=Hover" class="hoverImage card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Content</h5>
          <p class="card-text">View and update the content</p>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/content" class="card-link stretched-link"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you only want the image to change when it is hovered directly, then simply remove it from the stretched link. You can limit the "stretch" to the `.card-body` by adding `.position-relative`.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/stretched-link/#identifying-the-containing-block
*Optionally*, refactor the `div.my-image` into `a.my-image`, **but I think this makes for bad UX as it may be interpreted as having a different action when clicking the image vs. the rest of the card, when in your case it does not**.

```css
.my-image .mainImage {
  display: block;
}

.my-image .hoverImage {
  display: none;
}

.my-image:hover .mainImage {
  display: none;
}

.my-image:hover .hoverImage {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/content" class="my-image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png?text=Default" class="mainImage card-img-top" alt="...">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png?text=Hover" class="hoverImage card-img-top" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body position-relative">
          <h5 class="card-title">Content</h5>
          <p class="card-text">View and update the content</p>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/content" class="card-link stretched-link"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```